# Alt-tab icon list in Gnome and metacity?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, alt-tab, metacity

Can anyone provide a reference or explain how the icons to the alt-tab list is populated? I would like to specify some icons for some programs that do not have icons, e.g. xterm. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with Gnome 2 (Ubuntu Classic) and metacity as the window manager.

I did see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=630437) thread that mentions /usr/share/pixmap/, but if I use `cp gnome-terminal.xpm xterm.xpm` the icon was not populated in the alt-tab icon list (even after a logout/login). I do see that the icon is populated when I added the xterm command to the Program Menu.

Comment: just FYI, you're running an End-of-Life'd ubuntu release: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-October/000165.html: Please consider upgrading to a newer version.

Answer (score 2):

The window manager probably obtains this information from `.desktop` files. (I can confirm with GNOME 3 Shell, but should be the same in Metacity.)

These days every graphical program installs a file or several to `/usr/share/applications` (you can add your own to `~/.local/share/applications`). It's an INI-format file containing the basic information about that program according to [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/): name, primary executable, icon, ... For running programs, the window manager matches the window owner to the program named in `Exec=` line.

(When you add items to the GNOME menu, they are automatically stored in `.desktop` files.)

For example, I have written the following as `~/.local/share/applications/xterm.desktop` to make my Xterm have a generic "terminal" icon:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XTerm
Comment=Use the command line
Exec=xterm
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;TerminalEmulator;
```

The `Icon` key may be an absolute path to an image, or an icon name according to [Icon Theme Spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/). The system comes with `/usr/share/icons`, and you can put your own to `~/.local/share/icons`. (If it doesn't exactly match the naming spec, `hicolor/256x256/program.png` will be fine.)

Note that the preferred format is PNG, which has more capabilities than XPM.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried creating the `.desktop` files, and placed my icons in `~/.local/share/icons`.  This indeed influences the icons the application menu ("Windows start" button).  However, the icons in the alt-tab list still does not change.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Confirmed this is the case in both cases where the files are placed in the `/usr/share` and `~/.local/share`.

Comment: @Vinh: Even after restarting Metacity?

Comment: I restarted after every change (don't know how to restart Metacity itself).

Comment: any more thoughts???

Answer (score 1):

The name of the executable whose icon you want to have appear in the **alt-tab** listing and the name of the file in `/home/assure/.local/share/applications` must be the same in order for this to work.

Comment: I have the following:

$ cat .local/share/applications/xterm.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XTerm
Comment=Use the command line
Exec=xterm
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;TerminalEmulator;

Can you give an example for xterm?